# VBA column width update for Pivot table refresh

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table and a slicer and I need a code that will update the width of each column to fit the value every single time I update the slicer (which updates the pivot). I know that if I got to Pivot table > options, I cant select a box that says "autofit column widths on update", but it doesn't work. So instead I'm trying to make a code that automatically does that.

I tried this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        columns.autofit
    Next pt
End Sub
```

Something doesn't work though and I'm not sure what it is. Can anybody see an issue with the code? Thank you!

Comment: Can you take out the for `Each pt` part and just say `columns.autofit`?

Comment: @KateLO  have you read my answer  and code ? any feedback ?

Answer (score 4):

In order to modify the columns width in a `PivotTable`, you need to address the `pt.TableRange1.Columns` property.

Try the code below:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    pt.TableRange1.Columns.AutoFit
Next pt
```

Comment: Note that to access individual column's width, you'll need to use `.Columns(1).ColumnWidth`